# Why SQL case works that way?

Tags: mysql, sql

```
SELECT 
 CASE 'abc'
     WHEN true THEN 10
        WHEN true THEN 20
        WHEN false THEN 30
        WHEN 'abc' THEN 40
  end as abc
```

Returns 30

I expected 40, 10, at least 20, but it gave 30

Comment: You'll get the return value for the first true condition.

Comment: BTW, you should get an error. You can't compare character string literals and boolean literals like that.

Comment: It's a nonsense case statement and does evaluate to false but does not throw an error.

Comment: By my reading, since you're mixing [data types](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/type-conversion.html), you'll end up comparing these values as floating point values.

Comment: ***@P.Salmon***: it is a valid case statement. there is a difference in statements `if('abc', 'true', 'false')` and `if('abc'='abc', 'true', 'false')`. first one returns `false` and the second `true`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because MySQL [does not have a real boolean type](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/boolean-literals.html):

> The constants `TRUE` and `FALSE` evaluate to `1` and `0`, respectively.

[Type conversion](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/type-conversion.html) does the rest. I'm possibly wrong about the exacts details but I understand this is the rule that applies:

> In all other cases, the arguments are compared as floating-point (real) numbers.

Since `abc` casts to zero the first value that matches is `false`:

```
mysql> SELECT CAST('abc' AS DECIMAL), false;
+------------------------+-------+
| CAST('abc' AS DECIMAL) | FALSE |
+------------------------+-------+
|                      0 |     0 |
+------------------------+-------+
1 row in set, 1 warning (0.01 sec)
mysql> show warnings;
+---------+------+------------------------------------------+
| Level   | Code | Message                                  |
+---------+------+------------------------------------------+
| Warning | 1292 | Truncated incorrect DECIMAL value: 'abc' |
+---------+------+------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

In your original query, you can get further diagnostics if you ask for the warning messages:

```
mysql> SELECT
    ->  CASE 'abc'
    ->      WHEN true THEN 10
    ->         WHEN true THEN 20
    ->         WHEN false THEN 30
    ->         WHEN 'abc' THEN 40
    ->   end as abc;
+------+
| abc  |
+------+
|   30 |
+------+
1 row in set, 1 warning (0.01 sec)

mysql> show warnings;
+---------+------+-----------------------------------------+
| Level   | Code | Message                                 |
+---------+------+-----------------------------------------+
| Warning | 1292 | Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value: 'abc' |
+---------+------+-----------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Answer (score 0):

### ***Accord with this [Sintax](https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/case.php):***

```
SELECT table_name,
CASE [ expression ]

   WHEN condition_1 THEN result_1
   WHEN condition_2 THEN result_2
   ...
   WHEN condition_n THEN result_n

   ELSE result

END
FROM all_tables;
```

---

### *Your script looks like this:*

```
SELECT 
CASE 'abc'
        WHEN 'abc' THEN 10 -- True
        WHEN 'abc' THEN 20 -- True
        WHEN 'bca' THEN 30 -- False
        WHEN 'abc' THEN 40 -- True
END
```

*YOU WILL OBTAIN THE FIRST VALUE THAT COMPLY THE CONDITION*